# Filtering specific text from log file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

So I have a log file from Twitch chat and I want to make a word cloud, to do this I only want the texts after their name eg.

```
[Jun 01 2015 02:23:58 UTC] swimsphinx: test1
[Jun 01 2015 02:24:15 UTC] swimsphinx: test2
[Jun 01 2015 02:27:36 UTC] swimsphinx: lol
```

I want to process the whole file so that the date and name are removed so i'm left with 3 lines

```
test1
test2
lol
```

Is this possible in windows CMD? Or is there something else i should do?

Comment: Would you mind running powershell instead of CMD?

Comment: sure, anythingg

Comment: You can do this with any programming language with the power of regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(EDIT: Just for clarity, as noted by David, this isn't going to work in the generic windows `cmd` interpreter. This is more of a powershell one-liner)**

You could do something like this:

`cat chat.log | %{$_ -replace "\[[^]]*\] +[^ ]*: ",""} > words.txt`

Translated: read the contents of `chat.log`, then pipe that into a command to replace anything that looks like a timestamp/username thingthe front of each line and put the result into `words.txt`

I took a guess as well, that for odd cases like:

> `[Jun 01 2015 02:24:15 UTC] swimsphinx: test2 [Jun 01 2015 02:24:15 UTC]  swimsphinx: message`

you want to get

> `test2 message`

rather than

> `test2 [Jun 01 2015 02:24:15 UTC]  swimsphinx: message`

Comment: @friendman "Is this possible in windows CMD?" - Please share how this works in cmd ... this look like a bash (or cywin) solution which is not what you asked for.

Comment: @DavidPostill I asked in the comments if powershell was an option (and apparently, it is) and the question is "Is this possible in windows CMD? Or is there something else i should do?"

Comment: @DavidPostill Just for clarity as well, added an edit to my answer to make it clear I'm not going for a `cmd` solution. This is a powershell solution

Comment: Fair enough. It wasn't obvious to me that it was a `powershell` script :(

Comment: @DavidPostill I must admit it's pretty terse, *NIX-like syntax (and regexps are never that pretty) but I've found it a surprisingly handy pattern for throwaway things like this.

Comment: @He he. I should teach myself powershell (I haven't bothered so far as most tasks can be done with batch files) ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I filter specific text from a log file?

```
[Jun 01 2015 02:23:58 UTC] swimsphinx: test1
[Jun 01 2015 02:24:15 UTC] swimsphinx: test2
[Jun 01 2015 02:27:36 UTC] swimsphinx: lol
```

If the lines are always in the same format you can use the following batch file.

test.cmd:

```
echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=4 delims=:" %%a in (log.txt) do (
  set _txt=%%a
  echo !_txt:~1! >> filtered.txt
  )
```

input:

```
C:\test>type log.txt
[Jun 01 2015 02:23:58 UTC] swimsphinx: test1 abc
[Jun 01 2015 02:24:15 UTC] swimsphinx: test2
[Jun 01 2015 02:27:36 UTC] swimsphinx: lol

C:\test>
```

output:

```
C:\test>type filtered.txt
test1 abc
test2
lol

C:\test>
```

notes:

- hard coded with input file `log.txt` and output file `filtered.txt`, you could pass these names into the batch file as parameters.
- with the format you provided the text you want to extract is the 4th token when the delimeter is a colon (`:`).
- `set _txt=%%a` followed by `!_txt:~1!` is used to strip the space following the 4th `:`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)'s answer, but you can use a wildcard to remove everything before a substring.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
    set line=%%a
    echo !line:*swimsphinx: =!
)
endlocal
```

Pass the name of the text file into the script when you call it (or replace %1 with your text file name).

Answer (score 0):

Here comes my personal choice using [PythonPy](https://github.com/Russell91/pythonwpy). Works across multiple OS and you can reuse your Python knowledge. Even if you don't know Python learning it would be easier than spending time with Awk & Sed stuffs.

Here's how you need to start.

1. Install PythonPy for windows

   `pip install pythonwpy`
2. Use this command `type test | wpy -x 'print(x.split(" ")[-1])'` to parse your log file.

Here is what I tried and got:

```
nehemiah@neo ~> type test.txt
[Jun 01 2015 02:23:58 UTC] swimsphinx: test1
[Jun 01 2015 02:24:15 UTC] swimsphinx: test2
[Jun 01 2015 02:27:36 UTC] swimsphinx: lol
nehemiah@neo ~> type test.txt | wpy -x 'x.split(" ")[-1]'
test1
test2
lol
```

3. You can learn much more exciting features for Windows [here](https://github.com/Russell91/pythonwpy) and for Linux/OSX [here](https://github.com/Russell91/pythonpy)

Answer (score 0):

Not a cmd solution and loving Powershell but this is actually one of vim's fortes.

```
%s/.*:_
```

and you're done.

*_ being the space character*